# How to get content in a header using XPath

Tags: html, xpath, yahoo-pipes

I'm extracting content from a web page using Yahoo Pipes. For some reason, the developer placed the article content within `<h2>` tags and I'm having difficulty getting the content from there.

The content looks like this:

```
<div id="divid"><h2>
<p>Some content<p>
<p>Some more content</p>
</h2>
<!-- some more stuff here -->
</div>
```

When I use `//div[@id='divid']` I can fetch the content of the whole `<div>` block, but when I try `//div[@id='divid']//h2` or `//div[@id='divid']//h2/text()` I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the content between the `<h2>` tags correctly?

You may want to check the actual [web page](http://birgun.net/yazi-goster/unal-ozmen/13-9-2013/duz-liselerin-yerini-imam-hatip-liseleri-aldi-563.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you were missing is ticking the **Use HTML5 parser** option. Without that it could not match `//h2`.

That page is quite a piece of work. The text is full of `<span...>` tags with inline styles. I created a sample pipe to make some sense out of the page:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=cf46006f77bdac4a6e57785c78cd0b2b

Comment: Yes, it was the HTML5 parser option. Thanks!